# GAS displays 'We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND.' when I try to deploy

Tags: google-apps-script

GAS can no longer be deployed.

When I try to deploy, the following screen is displayed from around 10/22.
Test deploy is as well.

Until then I did nothing.
The script is in share drive.

[image: figure]

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved it myself.

This project was using a library and it was broken (I don't know why because I did nothing.) and resolved when I redeployed it.